# "Normal world" as a flashback

Tags: protagonist, flashback

I'm toying with the idea of starting off with the MC freshly landed in his new world. But I  reveal the a) Normal World and b) Inciting incident using through two methods. 1. The Normal world is revealed in a flashback. 2. The inciting incident is revealed via a conversation that the MC has with characters from his new world.

What are the pros and cons of doing it this way? Has it been done, any examples?

Answer (score 1):

Every story has an arc: It begins with the normal, "uneventful" life of the protagonist. Then something happens (the inciting incident) that makes it necessary for the protagonist to do something (undertake a journey and kill the dragon) to return their world to the state it had before. Usually the hero returns to find his world changed, despite his success.

When you narrate such a story, you can begin anywhere. There are narratives that begin in the thick of the action, there are narratives that begin at the end of the story, and there are narratives that begin long before the beginning (in a prologue).

Wherever you begin, the purpose of that beginning is to hook the reader. You want them to want to know what happens next.

In your case, the new world (and wanting to explore it alongside the protagonist) might be (one of) the hook(s).

It is perfectly fine to reveal the background of the hero to the reader as we follow him along. After all, that is how getting to know someone usually works in the real world, and most of us find this fun (think of falling in love!).

There are no pros and cons to where you begin the narrative. What you need is a strong hook and a thrilling development that balances satisfying intermediary achievements (another clue found in the detective novel) and rising tension (the murderer managed to escape after the detective got as close as never before) and thus keeps the readers hooked.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the status-quo of the character before the inciting incident through flashback is a sound technique for telling a story. As is having the inciting incident happen before the start of the story. I think that is the method used in Roger Zelazny's "Nine Princes of Amber." It depends on what you interpret as the inciting incident. For Corwin, I think the inciting incident that turns him into Corey is when he is nearly beaten to death by his brother and dumped in Europe during the Black Plague to die.

It is an effective method because it lets the story start nearer to moments of action -- that whole in media res thing -- and avoid the slow wind up of the story.

Having the details of the inciting incident be revealed only through character dialogue sounds like a more involved matter. On the surface it sounds like ***exposition masquerading as dialogue***.

If the sole purpose of the discussion between the characters is to get the inciting incident into the story then it is likely to come across as an infodump in sheep's clothing. That also depends on how long it takes.  If the whole discussion is a page long then it is no likely to matter.

If the purpose of the dialogue is doing several things like building character and setting stakes and revealing complexity and as a by-product the character's inciting incident emerges than it is likely to be terrific. Writing that can do this second thing is engaging and immersive and takes a great deal of skill as a writer to execute. Writing ***exposition masquerading as dialogue*** isn't hard and is often not engaging and a slog to read.

Comment: @Humpback, these clarifications ought to be added to your question rather than communicated through comments to specific answers. That tends to  improve the question, which tends improve the quality of answers you’ll get.